# IF EXISTS command appears to be executing, even when condition doesn't exist?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have the following SQL statement within a large update script:

```
...
PRINT N'Updating Table_01, Applying TypeReassignment from YesNoField_01 data'
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.columns WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[Table_01]') 
         AND name = 'YesNoField_01')
    BEGIN
        UPDATE Table_01 SET TypeReassignment = CASE YesNoField_01 WHEN 'Y' THEN 2 ELSE 1 END 
            WHERE TypeReassignment = 0
    END
 ... 
 //script continues with other modifications.  Towards the end of my script 
 //the YesNoField_01 field is dropped from the table.
```

The intent of the IF statement is to execute an UPDATE on a specific column *only if* another field exists on the table.  As my comment at the end suggests, I am removing this original column (`YesNoField_01`) towards the end of my script.

The purpose of the IF check is so the script can be executed multiple times, even if it has been executed once before.  If part of this script has been executed, it needs to skip over completed steps and continue execution without any errors.  In this case, I need to skip over a data update.

However, if I execute my script on a database that has already had this script executed once before, I am getting the following error.

> Invalid column name 'YesNoField_01'

When I navigate to the failing statement, it appears that the script is attempting to execute the UPDATE command within the IF block.  When you independently execute the `SELECT * FROM sys.columns WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[Table_01]') AND name = 'YesNoField_01'` statement, you see that nothing is returned because the field `YesNoField_01` has already been removed from the table.

I'm confused.  If my SELECT statement does not result in an existing record, why am I getting an execution error from within the IF block?  Or, a better question, why is it even trying to execute my IF  block when the IF conditional should evaluate to false?

Comment: Well one of the solution to get rid of this error is make your update statement dynamic.

Comment: @KrishnrajRana Explain please.

Comment: The parser will not skip validation of the UPDATE statement because its in an IF block, once you drop the column your SQL becomes invalid because you attempt to reference a column that no longer exists (the fact the IF is FALSE is not relevant)

Comment: @AlexK.  Well, this is the odd thing.  I attempted this script (multiple times) on my dev server last week.  Sure enough, it worked!  However, after this weekend, when the dev db was refreshed, someone executed this script for me.  Not knowing they had done this, I executed it again.  It should have behaved as I saw it behave when I originally wrote this code last week-- the script executes correctly on both the first and following executions.  However, this morning it still fails.  Could this still relate to your response?

Comment: It would work if the column existed and was never dropped, it would  *parse* if the *table* did not exist (DNR) but AFAIK it will always fail if the column does not exist in an existing table, E.g. `if 0=1 select i_dont_exist from atable` will always fail

Comment: @AlexK.  The column does not exist.  If I close & re-open SSMS, and browse to the columns list, it does not exist.  Also, to be sure, the table exists and is not dropped and reloaded.

Comment: Try wrap it all in a proc. We do many procs where all, some or none of the schema/columns exits and we handle it with if statements just like you do and it works fine.

Comment: @EugeneNiemand  Unfortunately, I can't do that.  This is part of a major server update.  My (large) script is part of a much larger update.  If I create an SP, I then have to clean-up removing the SP after it has completed it's purpose.

Comment: You can do it dynamically; build the SQL statement in a string and EXEC/sp_executeSQL it

Comment: Step 1) Compile the SQL. Step 2) Run the SQL. Unfortunately, the way that SQL Server works, step 1 needs to be able to resolve all schema references, so non-existent columns causes step 1 to fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you could alter the test to check for the column's existence indirectly, thus:

```
DECLARE @YN_FieldName sysname =  
(
   SELECT Name 
   FROM sys.columns 
   WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[Table_01]') 
      AND name = 'YesNoField_01'
)

IF @YN_FieldName IS NOT NULL
   BEGIN
      UPDATE
         Table_01
      SET TypeReassignment = 
         CASE YesNoField_01
            WHEN 'Y' THEN 2
            ELSE 1
         END
      WHERE
         TypeReassignment = 0
   END
```

I suspect, though, that dynamic SQL will be required.